# DB2 LUW : Create User Defined Function inside Dynamic SQL

Tags: plsql, db2, db2-luw

Can we create user defined funciton with Dynamic sql statement in DB2 LUW 10.5 Verison?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Db2-LUW v10.5 allows 'create or replace function' to be run by EXECUTE IMMEDIATE etc. For example:

```
$ db2 -tvf dyn_fn2.sql
begin
  execute immediate 'CREATE or replace FUNCTION MYSQRT (X DOUBLE, Y DOUBLE) RETURNS DOUBLE RETURN SQRT((X*X) + (Y*Y))' ;
end

DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

$
```